# Altering what will appear on different fragments (Navigation Drawer)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I'm back on again. My last attempt at the Navigation Drawer failed, so I have started it with fragments (going much better this time). Anyways, I have got to the point where the fragments are loading etc, but I have no idea where it edits what appears in each fragment.

I was assuming there was a separate thing for each fragment, but I can't find it, if you guys can help that would be great.

So basically, my question is, how to tell the different fragments what to display? I have a feeling it is in the    onCreateView method but I'm not sure..

Here's my code:

```
package com.example.android.navigationdrawerexample;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.SearchManager;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout DrawerLayout;
    private ListView DrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle DrawerToggle;

private CharSequence DrawerTitle;
private CharSequence Title;
private String[] pageArray;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Title = DrawerTitle = getTitle();
    pageArray = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pageArray);
    DrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    DrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.left_drawer);

    // set a custom shadow that overlays the main content when the drawer opens
    DrawerLayout.setDrawerShadow(R.drawable.drawer_shadow, GravityCompat.START);
    // set up the drawer's list view with items and click listener
    DrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.drawer_list_item, pageArray));
    DrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

    // enable ActionBar app icon to behave as action to toggle nav drawer
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    // ActionBarDrawerToggle ties together the the proper interactions
    // between the sliding drawer and the action bar app icon
    DrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this,                  /* host Activity */
            DrawerLayout,         /* DrawerLayout object */
            R.drawable.ic_drawer,  /* nav drawer image to replace standard image in action bar */
            R.string.drawer_open,  /* "open drawer" description for accessibility */
            R.string.drawer_close  /* "close drawer" description for accessibility */
            ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(Title);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            getActionBar().setTitle(DrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu(); // creates call to onPrepareOptionsMenu()
        }
    };
    DrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(DrawerToggle);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        selectItem(0);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

/* Called whenever we call invalidateOptionsMenu() */
@Override
public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // If the nav drawer is open, hide action items related to the content view
    boolean drawerOpen = DrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(DrawerList);
    menu.findItem(R.id.action_websearch).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
    return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
     // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
     // ActionBarDrawerToggle will take care of this.
    if (DrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
        return true;
    }
    // Handle action buttons
    switch(item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.action_websearch:
        // create intent to perform web search for this planet
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
        intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getActionBar().getTitle());
        // catch event that there's no activity to handle intent
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.app_not_available, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        return true;
    default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}

/* The click listener for ListView in the navigation drawer */
private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        selectItem(position);
    }
}

private void selectItem(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = new PageFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt(PageFragment.ARG_PAGE_NUMBER, position);
    fragment.setArguments(args);

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    DrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(pageArray[position]);
    DrawerLayout.closeDrawer(DrawerList);
}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    Title = title;
    getActionBar().setTitle(Title);
}

/**
 * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
 * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
 */

@Override
protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
    DrawerToggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
    DrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}

/**
 * Fragment that appears in the "content_frame", shows a planet
 */
public static class PageFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ARG_PAGE_NUMBER = "page_number";

    public PageFragment() {
        // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_planet, container, false);
        int pgNum = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE_NUMBER);
        String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pageArray)[pgNum];

        int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                        "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
        ((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
        getActivity().setTitle(planet);
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

}

If you can help me out, that would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look in your `selectItem` method, which is called whenever a tab is selected.

It currently creates a new `PageFragment` instance:

```
Fragment fragment = new PageFragment();
```

And then passes the ID of the selected item as an argument:

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(PageFragment.ARG_PAGE_NUMBER, position);
fragment.setArguments(args);
```

That is to say, **no matter which item is selected, `PageFragment` is instantiated, just with different arguments.**

In `PageFragment`'s `onCreateView` method, this argument is retrieved and used to determine which planet to display:

```
int pgNum = getArguments().getInt(ARG_PAGE_NUMBER);
String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pageArray)[pgNum];

int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()),
                "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
```

So, that is 'where it edits what appears in each fragment'.

---

If you want to display a **different** fragment for each item in the drawer (probably a fairly common use case) then I would use a `switch` statement:

```
private void selectItem(int position) {

    Fragment fragment;

    // Select a different fragment based on which tab has been selected
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new TopDrawerItemFragment();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new SecondDrawerItemFragment();
            break;
    }

    // Replace the fragment
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();

    // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
    setTitle(mTabTitles[position]);
    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}
```

`TopDrawerItemFragment` and `SecondDrawerItemFragment` could be inner classes (like `PageFragment`) or separate Java class files.

Comment: Glad to be of service!

Answer (score 0):

You're selectItem method is setting up your fragment views. The lines

```
Fragment fragment = new PageFragment();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt(PageFragment.ARG_PAGE_NUMBER, position);
fragment.setArguments(args);
```

are creating the new fragment and setting its data where as the next 2 lines in the method

```
  FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit();
```

are changing the app's view to that of the fragment's (basically displaying that fragment). As for the fragment's view, the fragment'w own onCreateView method issetting up its view. Hopefully that helps